# not(:focus):before kills focus on editable div after clicking on some placeholder text

Tags: html, css, dom

I am having some troubles with an editable div and placeholder text that I wanted to insert over attribute mapping. `content:attr(data-text)` If you look at the example, the first line can be clicked anywhere and writing is possible instantly. For the other ones, text writing is only possible if you do not click at the placeholder text. Clicking the placeholder text has some chance to work but most of the time it is not getting focus until the user clicks again.

I broke this down and figured out that `not(:focus)` in the css is causing the troubles. I thought its exactly for those kind of interactions but it seems that the dom manipulation is the culprit.  Leaving it out will leave the placeholder on the div but clicking works. `user-select: none;` seems not to have any impact on this.

How can I prevent the div element from loosing the click focus instantly when working with `not(:focus)`?

```css
    [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text);
    cursor: text;
    color: red;
    }

    .edit {
    border: 2px dotted black;
    background-color: #CCC;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'>Working one</div>
    <div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
    <div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
    <div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
    <div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pointer-events:none;` seems to fix the weird issue. Probably because it prevent the pseudo element from catching the click event making the textarea to lose the focus.

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  cursor: text;
  color: red;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.edit {
  border: 2px dotted black;
  background-color: #CCC;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'>Working one</div>
<div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
<div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
<div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
<div class='edit' contentEditable=true data-text='Some text missing #####'></div>
```

Comment: Great, that exactly what I needed. Sometimes the answer is so simple.. and totally makes sense. Thanks!